# JAX-WS with Spring -- can't to execute method

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I read the book *Spring in Action*. And these have a chapter where you can see how to use remoting with Spring. I decided on the latter option -- JAX-WS. I do all that it done in the book, but I can't to execute method (make a space in the link):

> ServerSOAPFaultException: Client received SOAP Fault from server: Cannot find dispatch method for {http:// service.client1.mrchebik.ru/}getHelloWorld Please see the server log to find more detail regarding exact cause of the failure

So, I have these service endpoint:

```
@Component
@WebService(serviceName = "exampleService")
public class ExampleServiceEndpoint {
@Autowired
private ExampleService exampleService;

@WebMethod
public String getHelloWorld() {
    return exampleService.getHelloWorld();
}

@WebMethod
public String getMessage(String message) {
    return exampleService.getMessage(message);
}

@WebMethod
public String calculate(String condition) {
    return exampleService.calculate(condition);
}
```

}

And setting JAX exporter:

```
@Bean
public SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter jaxWsServiceExporter() {
    SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter jaxWsServiceExporter = new SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter();
    jaxWsServiceExporter.setBaseAddress("http://localhost:10000/ws/");

    return jaxWsServiceExporter;
}
```

On the client side, I have this setting:

```
@Bean
public JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean exampleService() throws IOException {
    JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean proxyFactoryBean = new JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean();
    proxyFactoryBean.setWsdlDocumentUrl(new URL("http://localhost:10000/ws/exampleService?wsdl"));
    proxyFactoryBean.setServiceName("exampleService");
    proxyFactoryBean.setPortName("ExampleServiceEndpointPort");
    proxyFactoryBean.setServiceInterface(ExampleService.class);
    proxyFactoryBean.setNamespaceUri("http://endpoint.service.client0.mrchebik.ru/");

    return proxyFactoryBean;
}
```

So, when I try to output a hello world from server, I get exception, considered at the start of topic.

This is a wsdl:
http://pastebin.com/Hdx1UH1W

**Solution:**

How noticed @efekctive, in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14710917/client-cannot-find-dispatch-method-for) have the same problem. So, I see, presumably the problem is due to *namespace*, and it doesn't use Spring.
I decide to change interface into Client (client1).

From:

```
@WebService
public interface ExampleService {
    String getHelloWorld();
    String getMessage(String message);
    String calculate(String condition);
}
```

To:

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://endpoint.service.client0.mrchebik.ru/")
public interface ExampleService {
    String getHelloWorld();
    String getMessage(String message);
    String calculate(String condition);
}
```

And after running, I get data from Server!

Comment: The exception has uri ...client1.. your code has ...client0...

Comment: because client0 -- server, and client1 -- client

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14710917/client-cannot-find-dispatch-method-for

Comment: hmm... How I can fix this in my cause? I have this link: `http:// service.client1.mrchebik.ru/` but I need in `http://endpoint.service.client0.mrchebik.ru/`?

Comment: @efekctive Thank you! I write a solution in my post.